# Concentration theorems for random points in a cuboid

Tags: probability-distributions, geometric-probability, concentration-of-measure

Given an $n$ dimensional cuboid (not cube) of unit volume if we pick two points in there from uniform distribution then what is there any concentration theorems that can be shown on the probability distribution of the distance?